# Signature plots definition

Tags: data-visualization

While reading some articles about High frequency statistics in financial markets, more precisely wile reading about microstructure noise, I was confronted by some signature plots simulated graphics.

It seems me to be a basic concept in statistics or, at least, just a well known term. However for a lack of culture on general statistics, I don't understand what it means (so neither what it illustrates) and I could not find this definition anywhere on the web.

Comment: Can you include a link to where you saw these plots & the context in which the term was used?

Answer (score 2):

Basically it plots the realised volatility against the sampling frequency.
https://mercury.smu.edu.sg/rsrchpubupload/5470/PhillipsYuCommentsJBES.pdf
The section 3 of this article gives a brief explanation. Hope it helps.